# Version of the guest operating system in VMware ESXi/vCenster

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, vmware-server

### short

Why are some Linux distributions in VMware ESXi/vCenster differentiated by version numbers when creating a VM and others are not?

### long

If you create a new virtual machine on a VM host VMware ESXi/vCenter and select the guest operating system family `Linux`, you have to select the version of the guest operating system afterwards, actually the distribution.

That these are differentiated according to 32-bit and 64-bit is understandable. But why are some distributions differentiated by version number and others not?

For example there are for Ubuntu altogether only the two entries:

- Ubuntu Linux (32 bit)
- Ubuntu Linux (64 bit)

For Debian there are two entries for each version number:

- Debian GNU/Linux 5 → 2 entries each for 32 and 64 bit
- Debian GNU/Linux 6 → 2 entries each for 32 and 64 bit
- Debian GNU/Linux 7 → 2 entries each for 32 and 64 bit
- Debian GNU/Linux 8 → 2 entries each for 32 and 64 bit
- Debian GNU/Linux 9 → 2 entries each for 32 and 64 bit
- Debian GNU/Linux 10 → 2 entries each for 32 and 64 bit
- Debian GNU/Linux 11 → 2 entries each for 32 and 64 bit

The same is with Fedora, this is differentiated, likewise like Ubuntu only after 32 and 64 bits, however RHEL and CentOS have, like Debian for each version number its own entry.

Is there a technical reason for this distinction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware will configure different default/recommended virtual hardware settings during VM creation depending on OS/distribution versions.

You will get different recommended settings and sometimes different value ranges and virtual interfaces depending on OS you select in VM settings as guest OS.

During certifications testings for different OS, they determine what are the minimal and recommended settings for different OS versions, and Linux distributions.

Take Debian 5 as example, it will not have same minimal and recommended memory settings as Debian 11.

Some distributions are more thoroughly tested and get more vendor support or community support, so have more differentiated recommended VM settings available.